# SSRS customized bar chart color

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've to show colors depending of the percentages of each bar in my chart report. 
I'm using a expression in a "Series Properties"

```
=IIf (Fields!TotalComplete.Value / Fields!TotalJobs.Value <= 85, "Red",
IIf (Fields!TotalComplete.Value / Fields!TotalJobs.Value >= 97, "Green", "Orange"))
```

But all bar are showing in Red color

What I'm setting bad?

Thanks,
Eliana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are comparing to 85 and 97 when you probably ought to be comparing to .85 and .97. Also, you need to work with aggregate values, like this:

```
=iif(sum(Fields!TotalComplete.Value)/sum(Fields!TotalJobs.Value) <= .85, "Red", iif(sum(Fields!TotalComplete.Value)/sum(Fields!TotalJobs.Value) >= .97, "Green", "Orange"))
```

If that doesn't solve the problem, try creating a table using the same groupings you have for your chart and put this expression into a text box so that you can see what value is calculating:

```
sum(Fields!TotalComplete.Value)/sum(Fields!TotalJobs.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u can try Switch Clause for this,
syntax will be

```
=Switch(
         (Fields!TotalComplete.Value / Fields!TotalJobs.Value) <= 85, "Red", 
         (Fields!TotalComplete.Value / Fields!TotalJobs.Value) >= 97, "Green",
          "Orange"
       )
```

Comment: .85 is working fine now, but how can I use when I want to use decimals? as sample red color when percentage is < 84.75

Comment: Just divide by 100 - use .8475